# How do I configure VSC to use coderunner and avoid getting "'scriptcs' is not recognized "

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm having issues getting CSharp code to run in visual studio using CodeRunner. Anyone know how to fix this error in the attached image?

[image]

I ALREADY know how to execute the prg using the terminal & DOTNET RUN command but I really would like to use coderunner.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is an old thread but i just figure out the answer so i think it may help someone else

you need to add

```
"code-runner.executorMap": { "csharp": "scriptcs -script" }
```

at your settings.json

in debian at least and i think in most linux based systems you will find it at ~/.config/Code/User